# How to hide instantiated gameobjects at a certain time point?

Tags: c#, instantiation, mesh, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I instantiated quads in my game (with code); overall 20 at y=-2 and 20 at y=2. Now I would like to hide one of them at a certain time point and for a certain period. 
How can I do this? My camera moves with a speed of 0.04f. 
I tried already

```
plotBars1.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled=false;
```

However, this hides all of them. Also my second array of instantiated objects (plotBars2).

Here the code of my script:

```
private GameObject bar1; 
private GameObject bar2; 
private GameObject[] plotBars1;
private GameObject[] plotBars2; 
private Vector3 posBar1; 
private Vector3 posBar2; 




// Use this for initialization
void Start () {


    bar1 = GameObject.CreatePrimitive (PrimitiveType.Quad); //create a Quad
    bar1.transform.position = new Vector3 (-5, -2, 0); 

    bar2 = GameObject.CreatePrimitive (PrimitiveType.Quad); //create a Quad
    bar2.transform.position= new Vector3 (5,2,0);

    //change material to green 
    Material Material= Resources.Load ("Material/green", typeof(Material)) as Material;
    bar1.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = Material; 

    //change material to green 
    bar2.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material = Material;


    //change scale of quad 
    bar1.transform.localScale += new Vector3(5f,-0.5f,0);
    bar2.transform.localScale += new Vector3 (5f, -0.5f, 0); 

    float sizebar1=bar1.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().bounds.size.x;
    float sizebar2 = bar2.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().bounds.size.x; 


    plotBars1 = new GameObject[20]; //creat an array of  quads.
    plotBars2= new GameObject[20]; //create an array of quads. 


    for (int m = 1; m < 20; m += 2) {

        plotBars1 [m].GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().enabled = false;

    }




    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        int initalposx1 = -5;


        posBar1 = new Vector3 (initalposx1 + (i*20), -2, 0);

        plotBars1 [i] = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate (bar1, posBar1, Quaternion.identity);

        plotBars1 [i].active = false; 

        }




    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {

        int initialposx2 = 5; 

        posBar2 = new Vector3 ( initialposx2+ (j*20), 2, 0);

        plotBars2 [j] = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate (bar2, posBar2, Quaternion.identity);



    }

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

}

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does `hide one of them` mean? Hide a random one? Hide one at a time sequentially through the array?

Comment: Hide means, that the player should not see bar 2 as soon as he leaves bar1 so that he has to know (based on experience) how fast and how high he has to move a certain game object. Do you understand what I mean?